# Sys table query for snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How do I find a table name in a stored procedure\view in snowflake with snowsql?

The SQL statement in SQL Sever equivalent is:

```
select distinct 
    [Table Name] = o.Name, [Found In] = sp.Name, sp.type_desc
from 
    sys.objects o 
inner join 
    sys.sql_expression_dependencies sd on o.object_id = sd.referenced_id
inner join 
    sys.objects sp on sd.referencing_id = sp.object_id
                   and sp.type in ('P', 'FN')
where
    o.name = 'YourTableName'
order by 
    sp.Name
```

Comment: Can you add more context? I don't know SQL server, but I want to know what you mean by "find a table name in a stored procedure"

Comment: Snowflake doesn't current have references like this in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.  @FelipeHoffa - I believe the question is asking how to find stored procedures that reference a particular table.

Comment: I am trying to find the snowsql code to see what stored procs reference a certain table.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake stored procedure definitions are stored in an object in the shared database Snowfalke, in schema Account_Usage and in table Functions.

select *
from functions
where upper(function_definition) like '%TABLENAME%'
and function_language = 'JAVASCRIPT';

It's not exact but should get you close to where you want to be.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answers there isn’t a direct equivalent. The following is a hacky and error prone way to achieve something similar.

```
SELECT procedure_schema,procedure_name, procedure_definition
```

from information_schema.procedures
where rlike(procedure_definition,'.*\bTABLE_NAME\b.*','si');

Very similar to the previous answer, but here I am using the information_schema.procedures. I am also using regular expression to match only the table name and avoid partial matches. Also notice the s and i parameters in rlike the s is used to allow . in regex to match new lines and the i is just to make the pattern case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring to this.

```
with recursive referenced_cte
(object_name_path, referenced_object_name, referenced_object_domain, referencing_object_domain, referencing_object_name, referenced_object_id, referencing_object_id)
    as
      (
        select referenced_object_name || '<--' || referencing_object_name as object_name_path,
               referenced_object_name, referenced_object_domain, referencing_object_domain, referencing_object_name, referenced_object_id, referencing_object_id
          from snowflake.account_usage.object_dependencies referencing
          where true
            and referencing_object_name = 'VIEW/FUNCTION' and referencing_object_domain='VIEW'
           and referencing_database = 'DB' and referencing_schema = 'SCHEMA'

        union all

        select referencing.referenced_object_name || '<--' || object_name_path,
              referencing.referenced_object_name, referencing.referenced_object_domain, referencing.referencing_object_domain, referencing.referencing_object_name,
              referencing.referenced_object_id, referencing.referencing_object_id
          from snowflake.account_usage.object_dependencies referencing join referenced_cte
            on referencing.referencing_object_id = referenced_cte.referenced_object_id
            and referencing.referencing_object_domain = referenced_cte.referenced_object_domain
      )

  select object_name_path, referencing_object_name, referencing_object_domain, referenced_object_name, referenced_object_domain
    from referenced_cte
;


---Specific for views inline tables

select * from table(get_object_references(database_name=>'DB', schema_name=>'SCHEMA', object_name=>'VIEW'));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).